# how to render fieldset , article for the form in react redux to make page beautiful?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, redux, material-ui

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>  
                        <fieldset>
                        <legend>Sign In</legend>                     
                        <Field name="username" component={rend`enter code here`erTextField} label="username"/>
                        <Field name="password" type ="password" component={renderTextField} label="password"/>
                        <FlatButton type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting} label="Sign In" />                        
                         </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

I'm rendering a login form in react-redux , I am trying to put an article and feildset to render it beautifully (For look and feel of UI) . Right now, fieldset is not properly giving me border around the form and the page looks weird. Can any one suggest how to render it beautifully. Thanks in advance .